# How to set the Background image for UIAlert view in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I want to set the custom image as background for alert view.If i set the image view frame size as static, then it displayed properly. But i have passed the message contents are dynamically displayed, so some times the contents is small and some times it comes huge amount of data displayed in the alert view.So how can i set the image view frame size which depends on the alert view frame size.

Here my sample code,

```
   UIAlertView *notesAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:notes delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];

   UIImage *alertBoxImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AlertViewBG.png"];

   UIImageView *_backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:alertBoxImage];

   _backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 282, 130);

   _backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

   [notesAlert addSubview:_backgroundImageView];

   [notesAlert sendSubviewToBack:_backgroundImageView]; 

   NSLog(@"The Alert view frame height %f and width %f", notesAlert.frame.size.height, notesAlert.frame.size.width); 

     // height 0.000000 and width 0.000000

   [notesAlert show]; 

   NSLog(@"After showing the Alert view frame height %f and width %f", notesAlert.frame.size.height, notesAlert.frame.size.width); 

    // height 173.800003 and width 312.399994
```

see my screen shot:

[image]

So how to set the image frame size which depends on the alert view frame?
Please Help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
_backgroundImageView.frame = notesAlert.frame;
```

Comment: i have tried that one, But no luck. See my updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the frame for UIAlertView in its delegate method `alertviewwillappear` to the uiimageview frame.
or you can use the `UIPopoverController` and add the bgimage for that.

Comment: UIPopOverController is said to be used exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.
Is there any other choice?

Answer (score 0):

See wordpress alert view as an example, http://ios.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/Classes/WPProgressHUD.m

Answer (score 0):

You have to go with subclass of UIAlertView in which override below methods...

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{   
    UIImage *alertBoxImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AlertViewBG.png"];
    CGSize imageSize = alertBoxImage.size;
    [self.imgBackground drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
}
```

To hide default background image of UIAlertView as you have shown in your screen shot

```
- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
    if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```